# Django Page Not Found Using SQLite3

Tags: python, django

Not sure why am I getting this error because I only have 1 item in my ToDoList called "Habibs List" but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/Habibs%20List, it's giving me this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Habibs%20List
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
<int:id> [name='index']
The current path, Habibs List, didn't match any of these.
```

This is in my view:

```py
def index(response, name):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(name=name)
    item = ls.item_set.get(id=1)
    return HttpResponse("<h1>%s</h1><br></br><p>%s</p>" % (ls.name, str(item.text)))

# def v1(response):
#     return HttpResponse("<h1>Game Page</h1>")

# def v2(response):
#     return HttpResponse("<h1>Electronic Page</h1>")
```

My URLconf:

```py
# the path to our different web pages
# like the different views we have in our file
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:id>", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Comment: You must give integer value before root url, but you gave 'Habibs%20List', which doesn't integer value.

Comment: could you further explain to me this problem I am fearly new to django  at the end of my url  I just add /Habibs List and I get the error and the %20 pops up

Comment: You have written `path("<int:id>", views.index, name="index")` path in your url, which gives id argument to your index function in `views.py`. You can change your `path()` in `urls.py` setting <str:arg> for place of <int:id>. Then in `views.py` overwrite your function - it must take one required argument `request` and `arg`. It must return html when rendered your queryset which you generated using `arg` parameter of **url**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must only change your url path to `path("<str:name>/", views.index, name="index")`